# Charging a single cell battery from two inputs

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging, charging

I'm trying to charge a single cell battery from two inputs, solar and USB. Currently, I have the battery charging only from solar using a [BQ24210](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/bq24210) charger. I have a USB connector on the PCB and I want to use it to charge the battery when it's connected, alongside the solar charger. This is what I have currently:

[image]

The charger I'm using, BQ24210, is a single input charger. Would it work if I connected both inputs to the charger like this? Or do I have to get a separate charger for the USB?

[image]

Comment: They make dual-input charger ICs specifically for USB + something else with all the changeover circuitry built-in.  Are you married to this specific charger?

Comment: Not necessarily no, I can switch it up if you have a recommendation that could work with solar and USB.

Comment: Recommendations for specific products are off-topic here, but if you just search for "dual input battery charger ic" you will find several.

Comment: I looked at a couple, most of them are USB and AC adapter. Will those work with the DC solar voltage?

Comment: You will probably want a solar MPPT controller or similar to maximize the power from your panel.  Some of the dual-input ICs may have that functionality built in, or you might need a separate controller IC for the panel; it might actually be easier to find a power controller for solar and USB and feed that into your existing chip.  I don't think its built-in MPPT will work well with USB in parallel and there are more efficient ways to connect your two inputs than diodes.  Look here for possible designs: https://www.digikey.com/reference-designs/en/energy-harvesting/solar-battery-chargers